# Convert foreach to LINQ with 'is' operator

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have to use LINQ/Lambda in stead of ForEach loop.
Below is my code

```
List<CatalogItem> catalogItems = new List<CatalogItem>();
foreach (TreeViewItem item in this.SelectedItems)
{
    if (item.DataContext is CatalogItem)
    {
        catalogItems.Add((CatalogItem)item.DataContext);
    }
}
```

I am wondering how to use 'is' operator in LINQ.

I have tried

```
this.SelectedItems
    .Where(item => item.DataContext is CatalogItem)
    .Select(item => item.DataContext)
```

but not getting desired result. 
please help.

Comment: And when you say "not getting desired result", could you tell us a bit about what you got, and why it wasn't what you wanted?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var catalogItems = this.SelectedItems
    .OfType<TreeViewItem>()//If the SelectedItems is IEnumerable
    .Select(item => item.DataContext)
    .OfType<CatalogItem>()
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
this.SelectedItems
.Select(item => item.DataContext as CatalogItem)
.Where(item => item != null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or like this:

```
var catalogItems = (from item in SelectedItems 
                    where item.DataContext is CatalogItem 
                    select (CatalogItem) item.DataContext).ToList();
```